# Can't boot due to graphic drivers Linux Mint

Tags: linux, rendering, driver, recovery, linux-mint

I've got troubles with my Linux.
Everything work perfectly before but once i've reboot it, i can't access to the login screen.
The only way to access to Mint (log, use it, etc) is to use the recory mode.
But i've got the message "running in software rendering mode...".

Can someone know how to resolve those troubles.

P.S :  Excuse me for my bad english

Comment: why you can't access to the login screen? it shows you a black screen or the system freezes?

Comment: i think that's a black screen. Nothing appended but it seems to work behind because the screen is not off.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue with ElementaryOS, a black screen showed up after the system logo animation, after researching I found that the problem was due to a glitch in my graphics driver.

So installing the default driver for my provider fixed that:

```
apt-get install nvidia-304
```

The following problem was a login loop (after entering my password and hit enter, it redirected me to login again). The solution was to reassign the permissions to my User:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER .Xauthority
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that's working perfectly.